# MySQL insert with the current timestamp

Tags: mysql

I have a table in mysql as shown below

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
id                  INTEGER(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
VendorName     VARCHAR(20),
Item             VARCHAR(20),
updated_at          TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
created_at          DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I need to insert record into it , I have tried as

```
Insert into Orders values(123,'PoppyCounter','Chocltae','now','now')
```

I got the output as

```
mysql> select * from Orders;
+-----+--------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id  | VendorName   | Item     | updated_at          | created_at          |
+-----+--------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 123 | PoppyCounter | Chocltae | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+-----+--------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Could anybody please tell me how can i make a insert with the current timestamp ??

Answer (score 7):

`now()` is a MySQL function on `current_timestamp`.
Where as `now` is a string literal and not equal to any date and time.

Your query should be:

```
Insert into Orders values(123,'PoppyCounter','Chocltae',now(),now())
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use [`now()`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_now.asp) (instead of 'now') as you are looking for the function and not for the string.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Eric. Why do you think this does not answer the question?

Comment: Looks more like a comment to me. Comments often contain answers, but answers are fleshed out to explain what the problem was a bit more. Also, before your edit it didn't contain any formatting and appeared to be of low quality, which is probably why it was flagged in the first place.